# How to query the bilaminar data in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class AddressRegion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)


class AvailableArea(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    addressregion = models.ForeignKey(AddressRegion, default=1)
```

In the template I want expediently to use the query models.

If now I query the datas I only knows use a for-loop:

```
addressRegions = models.AddressRegion.objects.all()

for ar in addressRegions:   
    availableArea = models.AvailableArea.objects.filter(availablearea = ar)
```

Then do some method to gather them.

Is there some simple method to do that? because I believe Django is kind to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get children you can use model name in lower case `_set` property:

```
ar.availablearea_set.all()
#            ^^^^^^^
```

or add [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

```
class AvailableArea(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    addressregion = models.ForeignKey(AddressRegion, default=1, related_name='areas')
    #                                                            ^^^^^
```

and use it

```
ar.areas.all()
```

Comment: availableArea or availablearea when I use the _set ?

Comment: model name in lower  case